# Standard warning triangle available in Cocoa for Mac OS 10.7

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion

does anyone know if and where the standard "Warning Triangle" to display problems is available to use in Cocoa-applications?

I mean the symbol that Mail.app displays in the sidebar when there is trouble with a mail-account.
If it is in the documentation I haven't found it yet.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`NSImageNameCaution`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000344-SW91) will give you the system image with the standard "triangle containing an exclamation mark".

Comment: Okay, I for the life of me do not know how I could have missed that. (I had that page open). Well... Thank you!